# Adjacent edges in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

May be a foolish question, but why is it always being said that "Two non-parallel edges are said to be adjacent if they are incident on a common vertex."

What about a situation where there exist more than two non-parallel edges having a common vertex?

I'm an extreme newbie to mathematics so if this is a foolish question kindly forgive me please..

Comment: The definition addresses a relationship between two edges.  It does not imply or require that only two edges can or should have the relationship of being *adjacent edges*.  Similarly we speak of two triangles being congruent without suggesting that there can only be two congruent triangles.

Comment: By parallel edges it means that there can be more than one edge associated with a given pair of vertices, say e1,e2 associated having the same end vertices v1,v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would not say the set of edges are adjacent, but that each of the pairs of edges are adjacent (or the set of edges are pairwise adjacent). This holds more generally than what you are saying, it implies that any two edges in the set share a common vertex (and does require that **all** the edges share the **same** common vertex).

The term "adjacency" mostly is used to refer to vertices, and is applied to edges through the idea of looking at the *line graph*, and whether two edges in the original graph correspond to adjacent vertices in the edge graph.

Answer (score 0):

All is incident at that vertex as apply definition for any two edges.

All vertices are adjacent, and all edges are incident.

Read for more [Graph theory: adjacency vs incident](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190709/graph-theory-adjacency-vs-incident)

Or [visit here for proof.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Adjacent_(Graph_Theory))

Answer (score 0):

It's just a choice of definition really. Being adjacent is something that two edges can be, because that is how we define it.

You are correct that if three non-parallel edges happen to have a common vertex, then it would make sense from an intuitive stand-point to speak of all three edges as adjacent. One could have defined it that way, but one hasn't.

Luckily, if $e$, $f$, and $g$ are three non-parallel edges that all have the vertex $v$ in common, then $e$ and $f$ are adjacent, $e$ and $g$ are adjacent, and $f$ and $g$ are adjacent, so not much is lost in not being able to talk about "the adjacency of three edges".

Comment: Two edges are called incident, if they share a vertex.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay yeah, I also believe that is the usual choice of words.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay By definition it is " Two edges e1,e2∈E of G adjacent if there exists a vertex v∈V to which they are both incident. "

Comment: Well, what about your query?

Comment: what I want to know is simply that is it safe to say that e1,e2,....,en∈E of G adjacent if there exists a vertex v∈V to which all the edges(e1,e2,...en) are incident

Comment: @SreejithCM yeah, it is safe to say. :)

Comment: @HowDoIMath I disagree, this would not be said for a set of more than two edges.  We *could* define adjacency however we want, but this is not how it is defined.